# How to make ui-grid one row as link button

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am new to angularJS and doing this project in which I used angular-ui-grid
in which i want make one Row as link, like I have user List and When I click on name of User it gets to details of that user I have done it with Table but how to do it with angular-ui-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `cellTemplate` option:

```
var userLinkTemplate: "<a href='/path/to/user/details/{{row.entity.userId}}'>user details</a>";

columnDefs: [{field: 'user', displayName: 'User', cellTemplate: userLinkTemplate}]
```

Comment: but one problem how can I put user name at User Details

Comment: `row.entity.userName`  (or however you named your field).  `{{row.entity.myFieldName}}`  Replace `myFieldName` with whatever you want.